# sql's avg function

Tags: mysql, sql, database

ques1. sql's where clause cant be used with  aggregate functions(sum,avg, max,min) ?

ques2. Considering a table named cust, containing columns: orderno, custid, cost

`select * from cust having cost> avg(cost)`

avg(cost) gives output 5695 therefore, 3 records should come in the output since they have cost greater than 5695. But only one is coming. On the other hand this query:

`select * from cust having cost>(select avg(cost) from cust)` gives correct output why?

Comment: MySQl or SQL Server? Make up your mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, use `HAVING`
2. Because MySQL doesn't implement SQL properly and does an implied `GROUP BY`
3. Because that is almost a correct query (see 2). It should be

   `select * from cust where cost>(select avg(cost) from cust)`

Comment: what is the point of having 'having' keyword if this query is wrong 'select * from cust having cost> avg(cost)'

Comment: You can do `HAVING AVG(Cost)>200` etc.